# unclosed parenthesis in custom endpoint in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I hve been having a number of problems recently with Wordpress and having AJAX responses with PHP errors saying
    Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 52 in /home/example/public_html/example.com/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 555

Line 555 is a preg_match

This has had me going (i kid you not) for TWO WEEKS 
I began to type the question but as can happen a lot, as i typed the question and broke down the code the answer came to me, the actions and code are below

I had this is the action:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('sutcalendar/v1', '/sendAgentRequest/(?P<ampm>\d+)/(?P<time>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
     'callback' => 'sut_set_agent_offer_endpoint',
    ));
});
```

This is the js script that calls it (all fields ar filled will provice an exampl api call)

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.standuptalent.com/wp-json/sutcalendar/v1/sendAgentRequest/" 
            + ampm + '/'
            + timeVal + '/'
            + day + '/'
            + month + '/' 
            + year + '/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jQxhr);
            }
        });
```

THe url it generates :

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/sutcalendar/v1/sendAgentRequest/pm/0830/27/2/2017/
```

And finally the endpoint itself:

```
function sut_set_agent_offer_endpoint(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $json = json_encode(array("post" => $_POST, "get" => $_GET));
    echo $json;
 return $json;
}
```

The error being returned is a PHP WP error :

```
 Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 52 in /home/example/public_html/example.com/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 555
```

Line 555 is a preg_match

This has had me going (i kid you not) for TWO WEEKS

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this is that I had changed the 'ampm' and 'timeVal' from hour and minute to the new names, forgetting I had not changed the regex for the action as well,

Changing the add action endpoint to

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('sutcalendar/v1', '/sendAgentRequest/(?P<ampm>\W+)/(?P<time>\W+)/(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
     'callback' => 'sut_set_agent_offer_endpoint',
    ));
});
```

Means that the first two are any url-encoded character, this also means you can post text area and multi-word text strings by url-encoding them first via JavaScripts encodeURI(value) function.

Anytime you are changing the enpoint or creating  new one and having issues with regexp encode the string and use \X* for the match